# Word cross referencing - how do I get rid of the dot?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am in the process of organizing cross references to tables, figures and chapter numbers in a book I am writing. So far I have completed the figures and tables without any problem. I just clicked "Insert" then "reference" then "cross reference" which then brings up a dialog box where I can select "table" or "figure". Then I am select "Insert reference to:" [Only label and number] and finally select from the list of figures or tables. I was hoping to do the same kind of thing for chapters, but there is no such item in the "reference type" drop down list. Instead it seems I have to select "numbered item". When I do this I do indeed see a list of my chapter names, along with their numbers. I notice that the numbers in the list are followed by a dot before the chapter title. I then go to the "Insert reference to:" drop down list and select "paragraph number". Then I click the [insert] button. The chapter number then correctly appears in my text, unfortunately it appears followed by a dot character that can not be deleted.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only reproduce this if the heading numbers have two dots after the digits, by changing the format in the multilevel list. Whenever they only have a single dot (fairly usual default), this does not appear in the cross reference.

This is the same if I use the Numbered items > paragraph number or Heading > Heading number options.

What version of Word are you using?

Comment: I work on this document using different versions of word when I am in different locations (using dropbox). The version I am using right now is 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to:

- 1. right-click on the selected cross reference section-> Then "Edit Field..." option.
- 2. It will appear a new window, just click at the "supress all non-delimiter chars". (As in the image)

[image]